# What is the standard terminology for the quantity $\|\nabla f\|_{L^2(\mu)} := \sqrt{\int_{\mathbb R^d}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2d\mu(x)}$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, norms, differential-calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ be a continuously differentiable function and let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb R^d$.

> **Question.** What is the standard teminology for the quantity $\|\nabla f\|_{L^2(\mu)}:=\sqrt{\int_{\mathbb R^d}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2d\mu(x)}$ ?

Comment: What is wrong with calling it L^2(μ)-norm of the gradient? You could also call it H¹-seminorm, if you like (i.e. canonical seminorm in the Sobolev space H¹).

Comment: Weighted Dirichlet energy?